# How can i group data in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

I used dependency Injection to get data and display in my view which all working great but i need your help to group my the result based on the ID field.

In my View i have this:

```
@inject ICompanyService companyListService

@{
    var ProductID = Model.ID;
    var compInfo = await companyListService.GetCompanyByID(ProductID); 
}
```

To create a list i used  this code

```
<ul id="list" style="line-height: 0.01;">
              @foreach (var item in compInfo)
                     {
                      <li data-expanded="false" class="panel-handler" data-id="@item.ID">@item.CompanyName                             
                              <ul>
                                 <li class="panel-handler" data-expanded="true" data-id="@subcontractor.ID">@scontractor.ContractorName</li>
                               </ul>                                                                
                       </li>
                    }
      </ul>
```

my data looks like as shown below

```
ID     CompanyID   CompanyName   ContractorName
255     13          MULETA PLC   YIBA ENGINEERING
255     13          MULETA PLC   SUNS CONST.
260     13          MULETA PLC   YIBA ENGINEERING
260     13          MULETA PLC   SUNS CONST.
```

I need your help to group the above data to get the following result.

```
MULETA PLC
    >>>YIBA ENGINEERING
    >>>SUNS CONST.
MULETA PLC
    >>>YIBA ENGINEERING
    >>>SUNS CONST.
```

My linq expression looks like

```
 var CompanyInfo =  await Context.Company
                           .Where(b => b.ProductID == request.ID)
                           .ToListAsync();
```

I need your help i group the result by ID field.

My API Controller

```
    [HttpGet("{ID}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCompanyByID(int produtID)
    {
        var company= await companyListService.GetCompanyByID(productID); 
        var companyList= company.GroupBy(x => x.ID);
        return Ok(companyList);
    }
```

And Result

```
[ [ { "ID": 13, "CompName": "MULETA PLC ", "ContractorName": "ENGINEERING" }, 
{ "ID": 13, "CompName": "MULETA PLC ", "ContractorName": "SUNS CONST." } ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to Linq with `using System.Linq;` and use `.GroupBy(x=>x.GroupByPropertyName)`

In your case it will be;

```
var CompanyInfo =  await Context.Company
                           .Where(b => b.ProductID == request.ID)
                           .GroupBy(b=>b.Id);
```

`CompanyInfo` is not a list but is a type of `Grouping<Key,Model>`. See the below code to access its values;

```
var CompanyInfo =  await Context.Company
                           .Where(b => b.ProductID == request.ID)
                           .GroupBy(b=>b.ResultId);

foreach(var request in CompanyInfo){
   Console.WriteLine(request.Key); // this will be the Request Id

   foreach(var properties in request){

      // this will be your model containing the properties
      Console.WriteLine(request);
      Console.WriteLine(request.Id);
      Console.WriteLine(request.CompanyId);
      Console.WriteLine(request.ContractorName);
   }
}
```

---

Try this simple markup first then just modify it according to your design. You need to make a nested loop;

```
<ul>
   @foreach (var item in compInfo)
   {
      <li>
         @item.Key.ToString() - @item.FirstOrDefault().CompanyName
         <ul>
            foreach(var record in item){
               <li>@record.ContractorName</li>
            }
         </ul>                                                                
      </li>
   }
</ul>
```

Comment: Jerdine, i get Thank you! but  `can't parse JSON.  Raw result:System.InvalidOperationException: Client side GroupBy is not supported.` Any idea?

Comment: hi @Rob you need to do it in your controller. Will you edit your question and show how you're doing it?

Comment: Please share your controller code that calls the API, and the view.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think it looks like working in Json but need one more help from you how can i update my foreach to display `[
  [
    {
      "ID": 13,
      "CompName": "MULETA PLC ",
      "ContractorName": "ENGINEERING"
    },
    {
      "ID": 13,
      "CompName": "MULETA PLC ",
       "ContractorName": "SUNS CONST."
    }
  ],`

Comment: Hi Jerdine, I updated my question added the API controller based on your suggestion and  it working but need your help updating the foreach in my view:) Thank you so much'

Comment: Thank you Jerdine, Json returns multidimensional type, using the foreach as is dont make any difference? `[ [ { "ID": 13, "CompName": "MULETA PLC ", "ContractorName": "ENGINEERING" }, { "ID": 13, "CompName": "MULETA PLC ", "ContractorName": "SUNS CONST." } ]` after i added the group the view doesnt load the API is fine it gives me the right information i am wonder do we have to update ` @foreach (var item in compInfo)`?